# Fill the Pandas cell based on dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

My Pandas dataframe is like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'dates': ['2/16/2023', '2/17/2023', '2/18/2023', '2/19/2023', '2/20/2023', '2/21/2023', '2/22/2023', '2/23/2023', '2/24/2023', '2/25/2023', '2/26/2023', '2/27/2023', '2/28/2023', '3/1/2023', '3/2/2023', '3/3/2023', '3/4/2023', '3/5/2023', '3/6/2023', '3/7/2023', '3/8/2023', '3/9/2023', '3/10/2023'],
        'Name': ['', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'D', '', '', ''],
        'Filter': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to fill the data frame using a dictionary below:

```
mapper = {0: {'begin': -3, 'length': 3},
          1: {'begin': -2, 'length': 2},
          2: {'begin': -3, 'length': 2},
          3: {'begin': -1, 'length': 2}}
```

So, For first A in the column filter is 0 which from above mapper dict should begin with -3 element and should continue for total 3 times.

Expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'dates': ['2/16/2023', '2/17/2023', '2/18/2023', '2/19/2023', '2/20/2023', '2/21/2023', '2/22/2023', '2/23/2023', '2/24/2023', '2/25/2023', '2/26/2023', '2/27/2023', '2/28/2023', '3/1/2023', '3/2/2023', '3/3/2023', '3/4/2023', '3/5/2023', '3/6/2023', '3/7/2023', '3/8/2023', '3/9/2023', '3/10/2023'],
        'Name': ['', 'A', 'A', 'A', '', '', '', 'B', 'B', '', '', '', 'A', 'A', '', '', '', '', 'D', 'D', '', '', ''],
        'Filter': [np.nan, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I can use bfill and fill. But, not able to use conditions.

Comment: i cannot reproduce your dataframe - `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
`

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop:

```
tmp = df.copy()
df[['Name', 'Filter']] = ['', np.nan]
for k, d in tmp['Filter'].dropna().map(mapper).items():
    idx = slice(k+d['begin'], k+d['begin']+d['length']-1)
    df.loc[idx, 'Name'] = tmp.loc[k, 'Name']
    df.loc[idx, 'Filter'] = tmp.loc[k, 'Filter']
```

Output:

```
        dates Name  Filter
0   2/16/2023          NaN
1   2/17/2023    A     0.0
2   2/18/2023    A     0.0
3   2/19/2023    A     0.0
4   2/20/2023          NaN
5   2/21/2023          NaN
6   2/22/2023          NaN
7   2/23/2023    B     1.0
8   2/24/2023    B     1.0
9   2/25/2023          NaN
10  2/26/2023          NaN
11  2/27/2023          NaN
12  2/28/2023    A     2.0
13   3/1/2023    A     2.0
14   3/2/2023          NaN
15   3/3/2023          NaN
16   3/4/2023          NaN
17   3/5/2023          NaN
18   3/6/2023    D     3.0
19   3/7/2023    D     3.0
20   3/8/2023          NaN
21   3/9/2023          NaN
22  3/10/2023          NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter names and values fo helper variables, remove missing values before and after mmapping vy [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), rewrite original values by empty string and `NaN`s and then set new values if match by dictionary if no missing value in `v`:

```
for k, v in df['Filter'].dropna().map(mapper).dropna().items():
    s = k + v['begin']
    e = s + v['length'] - 1
    name = df.loc[k, 'Name']
    val = df.loc[k, 'Filter']
    
    df.loc[k, ['Name','Filter']] = ['',np.nan]
    df.loc[s:e, ['Name','Filter']] = [name, val]
```

---

```
print (df)
        dates Name  Filter
0   2/16/2023          NaN
1   2/17/2023    A     0.0
2   2/18/2023    A     0.0
3   2/19/2023    A     0.0
4   2/20/2023          NaN
5   2/21/2023          NaN
6   2/22/2023          NaN
7   2/23/2023    B     1.0
8   2/24/2023    B     1.0
9   2/25/2023          NaN
10  2/26/2023          NaN
11  2/27/2023          NaN
12  2/28/2023    A     2.0
13   3/1/2023    A     2.0
14   3/2/2023          NaN
15   3/3/2023          NaN
16   3/4/2023          NaN
17   3/5/2023          NaN
18   3/6/2023    D     3.0
19   3/7/2023    D     3.0
20   3/8/2023          NaN
21   3/9/2023          NaN
22  3/10/2023          NaN
```

Tested if no match dictionary:

```
data = {'dates': ['2/16/2023', '2/17/2023', '2/18/2023', '2/19/2023', '2/20/2023', '2/21/2023', '2/22/2023', '2/23/2023', '2/24/2023', '2/25/2023', '2/26/2023', '2/27/2023', '2/28/2023', '3/1/2023', '3/2/2023', '3/3/2023', '3/4/2023', '3/5/2023', '3/6/2023', '3/7/2023', '3/8/2023', '3/9/2023', '3/10/2023'],
        'Name': ['', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', 'D', '', '', ''],
        'Filter': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mapper = {0: {'begin': -3, 'length': 3},
          1: {'begin': -2, 'length': 2},
          2: {'begin': -3, 'length': 2},
          3: {'begin': -1, 'length': 2}}
```

---

```
for k, v in df['Filter'].dropna().map(mapper).dropna().items():
    s = k + v['begin']
    e = s + v['length'] - 1
    name = df.loc[k, 'Name']
    val = df.loc[k, 'Filter']
    
    df.loc[k, ['Name','Filter']] = ['',np.nan]
    df.loc[s:e, ['Name','Filter']] = [name, val]
```

---

```
print (df)
        dates Name  Filter
0   2/16/2023          NaN
1   2/17/2023          NaN
2   2/18/2023          NaN
3   2/19/2023          NaN
4   2/20/2023    A     4.0 <- 4 not match dictionary, so no change
5   2/21/2023          NaN
6   2/22/2023          NaN
7   2/23/2023    B     1.0
8   2/24/2023    B     1.0
9   2/25/2023          NaN
10  2/26/2023          NaN
11  2/27/2023          NaN
12  2/28/2023    A     2.0
13   3/1/2023    A     2.0
14   3/2/2023          NaN
15   3/3/2023          NaN
16   3/4/2023          NaN
17   3/5/2023          NaN
18   3/6/2023    D     3.0
19   3/7/2023    D     3.0
20   3/8/2023          NaN
21   3/9/2023          NaN
22  3/10/2023          NaN
```